# Converting Mapserver default URL to a more user friendly version

Tags: mapserver, osgeo

I have a URL that I use to view my map generated using MapServer.

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/osm-google.map&mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all
```

How can I convert it to more general style such as http://foo.com ?

I just need to show my map in a specific URL like in maps.google.com or www.openstreetmap.com and nothing more. For example I want to hide my directories showing such as /home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/ in the original URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have apache, in your conf file (or .htaccess file) you can add the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mymapserver /cgi-bin2/mapserv.exe?map=/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/osm-google.map&mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all& [QSA]

RewriteRule ^mymapserverwms(.*) /cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/osm-google.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0& [QSA]
```

In that example, the URL `http://localost/mymapserver` will translate to your long string. 
Please check documentation in Apache for "RewriteEngine".

Cheers,
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MapServer variable `MS_map` as part of a SetEnvIf directive in your Apache configuration like:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/cgi-bin/mapserv" MS_map file=/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/osm-google.map
```